# How to generate a WAR with the source code in Maven?

Tags: maven-2, war

I want to distribute the war of my web application generated with Maven **with the source code** inside it. How to do that with Maven?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It is possible configure the maven-war-plugin to include the source directory as it was a web resource:

```
 <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <webResources>
            <resource>
              <directory>${build.sourceDirectory}</directory>
              <targetPath>sources</targetPath>
            </resource>
          </webResources>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

The java sources will be included in a `sources` directory in the war. Of course you should adapt the resource directory to your own maven layout.

Answer (score 8):

If you want the source files in the same directory as the class files you would use:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <webResources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>${build.sourceDirectory}</directory>
                        <targetPath>WEB-INF/classes</targetPath>
                    </resource>
                </webResources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually I think you would go this way: (this won't include the source files, but provides them as separate files)

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>attach-sources</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>attach-javadocs</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

At your war project's `pom.xml`:

```
<build>
    ...
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <attachClasses>true</attachClasses>
                    <classesClassifier>classes</classesClassifier>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            ...
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

In the projects you want do use it:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>my-war-group</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-war-artifact-id</artifactId>
    <version>my-war-version</version>

    <classifier>classes</classifier> <!-- THIS IS THE IMPORTANT LINE! -->
</dependency>
```