# WEB-INF/classes Contains my classes in both .class and .java extensions

Tags: java, eclipse, maven-2, classpath

I faced something little wierd recently, i noticed that my WAR project when its compiled and deployed by Tomcat using Eclipse, that the Folder WEB-INF/classes that should contains my classes in binary version : MyClass.class, containing actualy both .class and .java extensions  of my class. More clear, I have a Aclass.java, when i compile and run my web project, in WEB-INF/classes if got : Aclass.java and Aclass.class, when normaly i should find only : Aclass.class

I am using Eclipse Indigo / Managing with Maven2.0

Comment: Does this happen everytime? Did you try making a Clean prior to Build?

Comment: Yes, everytime ! I almost always do a build and clean before deploy

Comment: Why don't you show us your pom and explain us how you build your war? Without that information, the only answer we can give is "something is wrong. Fix it."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case, this was caused by Eclipse not properly respecting the settings in my `pom.xml`. Eclipse tries to read your `pom.xml` and configure itself to match. It does *not* run off the `pom.xml` directly.

I had to tweak Eclipse's settings manually. Specifically, under Project > Deployment Assembly make sure the 'Source' and 'Deploy Path' columns aren't mapping one of your source folders across to WEB-INF/classes.

Answer (score 0):

You can export the ".war" with source, probably that is what is happening in your situation. If you do "right click" on your project and select "export" > "war", you can "un-select" the "export source", among other details about the war to be generated.

In your maven you probably have some details to "point" to include your source files (for example in this question it is shown how to include source files: [How to generate a WAR with the source code in Maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642811/how-to-generate-a-war-with-the-source-code-in-maven), you should remove those if you do not want the source files in the generated WAR).

---

Excerpt of "configuration" part of pom.xml that does not include java source files:

```
<configuration>
    <classifier>dev</classifier>
    <webappDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}-dev</webappDirectory>
    <webResources>
       <resource>
          <directory>src/env/dev</directory>
             <includes>
                <include>**/*.properties</include>                                   
                <include>**/*.xml</include>
                <include>**/*.css</include>
                <include>**/*.html</include>                             
             </includes>
        </resource>
     </webResources>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I checked the link you provide but i don't have any of thoses specifications in my pom.xml

Comment: I have updated my question with a pom.xml "configuration" excerpt (from a project I am just working on). The "resource" contains most of the configuration files (including "properties" files, "WEB-INF/web.xml" files) used for a specific deployment of the project, in this case is the "dev" deployment target...