# include source files in war maven

Tags: maven, tomcat, maven-3, war

I want to include source files also in Maven - War file . Some plugins in maven will do that but they are including source files in classes folder. But my requirement is that when I import the same war file again into eclipse I should be able to work on that war like any other normal war.
Basically I should be able to work on the same war after importing it to eclipse when I build  maven project. (I'm using maven3. )

Comment: [possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642811/how-to-generate-a-war-with-the-source-code-in-maven)

Answer (score 0):

I remember that's not trivial because the war-plugin doesn't support the handy includes-configuration-element you know from the jar-plugin by default.

Therefore I suggest you to use the maven-assembly-plugin to configure the inclusion of your sourcefiles. You only need to define an assembly descriptor, where you list includes and excludes of your war-package. Maybe you can reuse one of the [predefinied assembly descriptors](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/descriptor-refs.html) to save some time.